# RoR - different object_id inside after_initialize callback after obj.reload

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, metaprogramming

I've written a method for my project which extends ActiveRecord models behaviour, I've stripped out most of it, consider the following code:

```
class ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.has_translations
    after_initialize :clear_translations_cache

    def clear_translations_cache
      binding.pry
      @_translations = {}
    end
  end
end
```

Basically, I want the @_translations instance variable to get cleared when I `.reload` the instance from the database, but for some reason, after fetching an existing object from the database, executing a method which populates `@_translations`, and then executing `object.reload`, `@_translations` still contains the same data.

I know for sure that the callback gets executed when first fetching the object from database and when calling `.reload`. I used binding.pry to halt execution inside the callback method, but for some reason `self.object_id` inside `.reload` has a different `object_id` than my original object, and therefore `@_translations` in the original object doesn't get cleared.

Attached is the console output:

```
1.9.3p194 :008 > s = TranslatedItem.first
   76:     def clear_translations_cache
=> 77:       @_translations = {}
   78:     end

[1] pry(#<TranslatedItem>)> self.class
=> TranslatedItem(id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
[2] pry(#<TranslatedItem>)> self.object_id
=> 70254243993580
[3] pry(#<TranslatedItem>)> exit
1.9.3p194 :009 > s.object_id
 => 70254243993580
1.9.3p194 :010 > s.reload
   76:     def clear_translations_cache
=> 77:       @_translations = {}
   78:     end
[1] pry(#<ServiceLevel>)> self.class
=> TranslatedItem(id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
[2] pry(#<TranslatedItem>)> self.object_id
=> 70254259259120
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm guessing the behavior you're seeing is related to how [ActiveRecord reload](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/81542f95d25825a7d3eff87d6f706661bf553b18/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb#L291-292) works:

```
fresh_object = self.class.unscoped { self.class.find(self.id, options) }
@attributes.update(fresh_object.instance_variable_get('@attributes'))
```

You'll notice that it is creating a fresh object by finding it from the database, which explains why you are seeing two different object_id values in your callback method. The object that is initialized during the reload is only used for its attributes and then goes out of scope.

It's not clear from your question whether you were just curious why it behaved this way or if you're looking for an alternative way to do it.

**Update:**

You've got a few options if you're just looking for a way to clear the instance variable when you reload the model.

1) Add your own reload method that you can explicitly call:

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  def reload_everything
    reload
    @_translations = {}
  end
end

object.reload_everything
```

2) Change the behavior of reload

```
module ReloadTranslations
  def reload(*args)
    super
    @_translations = {}
  end
end

ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, ReloadTranslations)
```

Comment: Actually, I was both curious and looking for an alternative way of achieving the instance variable clearance on reload. Do you see an elegant solution?

Comment: I added a few examples for alternate ways to do this. You will still need to have the translations be initialized when the class is instantiated, but one of the above should reinitialize it

Comment: Thanks for the help, isn't it a rails bug though? since for me this behaviour doesn't seem by design...

Comment: I wouldn't consider it a bug. The [API docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-reload) say it "Reloads the attributes of this object from the database.", but doesn't say it reinitializes the object.

Comment: I'm not talking about this, I'm talking about the fact that after_initialize callback should be in the scope of the original object and not the temporary one...

Comment: Got it. I'd post a question on the rails core mailing list and see what they say. https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/rubyonrails-core